# input type file path is fake - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, filepath, input-type-file

the code below must out put the path of the file **BUT** the out put is "C:\fakepath(file name)"

```
<html>

<body>
<form>
    <input type="file" id="file" onchange="document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = this.value;">
</form>
<p id="p"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what are you saying ? please show your codes

Comment: ok i added it ... there was a problem

Answer (score 1):

The value of an `input[type=file]` will never show anything related to the client filesystem. Only the file name is shown and the beginning of the path will always be `C:\fakepath` on a Windows machine (`C` also being a fake drive letter). That's just a feature implemented by browsers in order to preserve their users privacy and security (as a web application provider, you don't need to know the local path of the file that's being uploaded to you).

The reason why it returns a fake path (while it could just return the bare file name) is probably for backwards compatibility for old code that was written at a time when the real path was shown, and possibly parsed by the code. When the fakepath feature came up, this kind of code didn't break.

Comment: i have another input type file in the same page and its working but it is in a function and i dont know how does it show the true path

Comment: Really? Could you add the code that shows the real path in your question?